# Motional EMF in a wire in the plane of magnetic field and velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electricity

If velocity of a straight wire and magnetic field make acute angle and the wire lies in the same plane, is there an EMF developed in the wire? It is a thin wire. The velocity is perpendicular to it. I thought that there is no EMF because magnetic force is perpendicular to length and so charge separation does not take place. But the answer shows some non-zero value.

Answer (score 0):

To get the emf induced in a moving wire, use the component of the velocity which is perpendicular to both the wire and the magnetic field.